# LINQ expression to get child records with unique parent

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Here's a simplified version of my domain:

```
class Document
{
    int id {get;set;}
    string name {get;set;}
    List<Version> Version {get;set;}
}

class Version
{
    int id {get;set;}
    string name {get;set;}
    List<VersionActivity> VersionActivity {get;set;}
    [ForeignKey]
    int DocumentID {get;set;}
}

class VersionActivity
{
    int id {get;set;}
    DateTime DateOfActivity {get;set;}
    string ActivityName {get;set;}
    [ForeignKey]
    int VersionID {get;set;}
}
```

Looking for a LINQ query that returns the latest 20 Versions, but there can't be duplicate documents.

Example:

- I have 3 documents with ids of 1, 2 and 3.
- I edited (ie there was activity on) versions 10, 20 and 30 of Document 1 yesterday
- Today I edited versions 40, 50 and 60 of Document 2 (so these document versions come on top of a list of most recently edited documents).
- The query needs to return only the latest document version from Document 2 as record 1 and then the latest document version of Document 1 as record 2.

I want only one round trip to the database.  If this is easier with SQL, I can use that though I'd prefer LINQ queries.

Thanks.

Comment: The last point of your example means there are two versions of Document 2 in the query result?

Comment: There was a typo in my example which I fixed.  I changed bullet point 3 to refer to Document 2.  Basically, I want the most recently edited document versions -- but if there are more than one document version in that list having the same parent (Document), I want to exclude all but the first document version.

Comment: So if you have 50 Documents that have each been edited twice in the last 5 minutes, you only want the latest updated Version for the distinct Documents? (Sorry, the fact that you are only using 2 Documents in your example is confusing me a bit.)

Comment: Yes, thats exactly right.

Answer (score 0):

I think you question can be changed to 'List top 20 documents, in descendant order of update date'. Here is query

```
from d in documents
let latestVersion = (from v in d.Version
                    let latestDate = v.VersionActivity.OrderByDescending (va => va.DateTime).Select(va => va.DateOfActivity).First()
                    orderby latestDate descending 
                    select {Version = v, LatestDate = latestDate}).First()
select new {Document = d, Version = latestVersion};
```

Or if all version number are incremental for each document, just query

```
from d in document
let latestVersion = d.Version.OrderByDescending(v => v.Id).First()
select new {Document = d, Version = latestVersion};
```

Comment: I'm getting compile errors in the first example (va => va.DateTime) doesn't work -- and if that should read va.DateTimeOfActivity, then the following First function doesn't compile.  I've tried different things because I sort of see where you're going but I stuggle mightily with LINQ syntax

Comment: my fault. Updated First method.

Comment: Still not working...I modfied your code slightly because there is no DateTime field for VersionActivity...compile error comes at order by clause

Comment: Just change order by to orderby. My fault.

Comment: yeah, I fixed that but the whole select statement following that doesn't compile.

Comment: Compile in iPad is hard. Just add new after select keyword. Have you tried second solution, which is easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
//GET parent IDS  
var hiringStageIds = dbContext.JobRequisitionHiringStageSubStageLink.
                 Where(x => x.RequisitionTemplateID == RequisitionTemplatedId).Select(f =>
                 f.HiringStageID
            ).Distinct().ToList();


  var workflowIds = dbContext.JobRequisitionHiringStageSubStageLink.Where(d => hiringStageIds.Contains(d.HiringStageID)).Select(f => new
                { f.HiringStageID,
                    child =new { childs=                    dbContext.JobRequisitionHiringStageSubStageLink.Where(m=>m.HiringStageID==f.HiringStageID).Select(s=>s.HiringStagesWorkflowID).ToList()
                }
                }).GroupBy(x => x.HiringStageID).Select(y => y.First());
```